# Child's printf not displayed in parent process' console

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I have the following code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// child process is forked. 
// the child executes "ls -al"
// the parent process "waits" for the child and collects it

int main(void) {

    char *args[3];
    pid_t pid;

    printf("i am a parrent and my pid=%d\n",getpid());
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "fork error");
    else if (pid == 0) {
        /* child */
        printf("i am a child and my pid=%d",getpid());
        args[0] = strdup("ls");
        args[1] = strdup("-al");
        args[2] = NULL;
        if (execvp(args[0], args) < 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "exec error");
    }
    printf("my child got pid=%d\n",pid);
    /* parent */
    if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "waitpid error");
    exit(0);
}
```

which results in this output:

```
i am a parrent and my pid=11745 
my child got pid=11750 
total 144
drwxr--r-- 3 student student  4096 Jun 25 21:18 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 student student  4096 May 24 17:18 ..
```

some other files...

My question is:
Why child's `printf ("i am a child...")` output is not displayed in console and the output of `ls` is? What should I do to display it at same console as parent process?

Comment: Add a carriage return to the message. `printf("i am a child and my pid=%d\n",getpid());`

Comment: now it works.. but why it didn't without "\n"?

Comment: \r is carriage return \n is line feed

Comment: @MaxSegal because stdout is "line-buffered"; the file->buffer is only flushed when a '\n' is added (or when the buffer is full, of course). execxxx() doesnt care about buffering, so the message dies in the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a `fflush(stdout);` before the `fork`, or else you're likely going to have the output of
`printf("i am a parrent and my pid=%d\n",getpid());` in both you're parent's and your child's stdout buffer.
Then you need a `fflush(stdout)` or `fcloseall()` before the `exec` call, because an `exec` completely wastes your old process image and your output buffers with it.

Alternatively, you can switch to line buffering or turn it off.

In handling the `exec` error, you should also `_exit` in addition to printing the error, or else it'll continue down it's parent's route.